# Error in installing ROS indego Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I tried to download ROS indigo more than 3 times and I always receive the same error in the end of the installation : i followed the instructions here:

http://wiki.ros.org/indigo/Installation/Ubuntu

my laptop is 14.04 LTS

```
N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension

N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.listsudo' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
```

what is the solution ??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/232656/error-in-installing-ros-indego-ubuntu-14.04-lts/) by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2016-04-22

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tomatofish](https://answers.ros.org/users/27833/tomatofish/) on 2016-08-25**:
Hi, I got the same problem on Ubuntu 16.04.1. I tried to remove the bad file but useless.
Hope someone can solve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you did not execute step 1.2 correctly. Did the command prompt you for additional input or give you some other sort of strange prompt after you tried to execute:  `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'` (Note that the entire command should be entered on a single line)

You should remove the bad file with: `sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.listsudo` and execute step 1.2 again.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2016-04-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on 2016-04-23**:
when i tried to remove it , i recived this message : sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.listsudo
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.listsudo’: No such file or directory

again , nothing happened when i executed the deb packages , dont know why

**Comment by [Omarzamany](https://answers.ros.org/users/26677/omarzamany/) on 2016-04-23**:
it asks me to enter the password and then the terminal allows me to enter a new line immediately

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-24**:
It sounds like the bad file has been removed somehow. "execute the deb packages" is not a thing I understand. Please be more specific or list the exact command you're running.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-24**:
If `sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu $(lsb_release -sc) main" > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list'` works correctly, it should not print anything and should return you to the shell prompt.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2016-04-24**:
You should then continue with the rest of the install steps, starting with step 1.3